# Getting Excel to automatically write in values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1")

    If Not Intersect(Target, KeyCells) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A2", "A" & KeyCells.Value).ClearContents
        For i = 0 To KeyCells.Value
            Cells(i + 1, "A").Value = i + 1
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to enter a value into A1, such as 10, and have excel list out the numbers 1, 2, 3 etc in A2, A3 and so on.

Comment: what does the code do that is not correct?

Answer (score 3):

`Range("A2", "A" & KeyCells.Value)` from your code is incorrect. You can use either

`Range("A2:A" & KeyCells.Value)` or `Range(Range("A2"), Range("A" & KeyCells.Value))`

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1")

    If Not Intersect(Target, KeyCells) Is Nothing Then
        Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).ClearContents
        For i = 1 To KeyCells.Value
            Cells(i + 1, "A").Value = i
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Your range object was malformed and you should always turn off events before writing back to the worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long, KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1")

    If Not Intersect(Target, KeyCells) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("A2:A" & CLng(KeyCells.Value)).ClearContents
        For i = 0 To KeyCells.Value
            Cells(i + 1, "A").Value = i + 1
        Next i
    End If
safe_exit:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I was debugging and left it commented.